# JPG image shows from phone but not from server - android

Tags: android

In my app I am able to pick up a picture from the Gallery and show it on my phone. The picture has extension JPG. But when I email it to myself, save it on the server and then try to display it on my phone, it does not display. I even tried to downsize it to 30% using my email app on the phone, so now it is 220KB instead of 1.4MB but it still does not display.

In both cases I use the method

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(personPicture))
```

What do I need to do to overcome this problem?

BTW: the name of the picture was changed when I saved it on the server. I do not think it matters but I mentioned it anyway.

**EDIT**

The above is all the code I am using. Just to complete the issue here is the code that handles both jpg and png and it works if the picture is renamed to png.

```
            if (url.contains("jpg")) { 
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url));
            } else {
                Drawable drw = LoadImageFromWebOperations(url);
                if (drw != null) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(drw);
                }
            }
```

Note: the 1.4MB PNG file worked fine on the emulator but gave Out of memory exception on the device. When I re-sized the PNG file to 350KB it displayed properly on the device also.

If needed here is the url used in the above code (a picture of a cat)/

```
http://212.150.56.58:8080/feedback/pictures/56.png
```

Comment: After saving it on server How you display the image? post that code and image URL after saved on server

Answer (score 1):

When you try to load image from server into app, load it using `Picasso` library like as below:

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("image_to_be_loaded").into(profile_image);
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to use third party library then try the following code:

```
public Drawable loadImageFromURL(String url, String name) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, name);
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to use third party library

Comment: @Zvi but it will load it fast.

Comment: @Zvi well if you don't want to use this, show some code so that i can check where the problem is.

Comment: See my edit, although the code shown is all the code I used. In any case I will try your code as well.

Comment: What is the 'name' parameter? my url has the filename as part of it. Is it a temp file?

Comment: @Zvi this is just a name you want for your file.  Actually this is in the method so you have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso to load server images to your app image view it also supports caching and lot many features.

Use is like this

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

checkout [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why, but if I renamed the picture on my server to extension PNG the picture displays, in all sizes.

Comment: Silly me. The renaming of the picture to PNG caused my app to use my custom 'LoadImageFromWebOperations()' which used

           ' InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(strPhotoUrl).getContent();
            return Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");"